# Keeping google signin token in sync with a server token

Tags: google-signin

I'm going to use google signin on a javascript web app.
Once the user signs in I receive an id_token. I then send this to my server to validate the token, locate the user in my own database, and return an access token for my server api.

Is it a good idea to keep the access token I generate in sync with the state of the google token? E.g. if the google token expires, also expire my server access token?

Comment: As I work on a related task, I found this resource was very informative, specifically the section on server flow - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow